# Highcharts (Highstock) how to catch errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there any way to catch the errors thrown by Highcharts? Especially the `Invalid negative value` error which is quite common in my case whenever my app switches to a different dataset on the server.

I'm looking forward to something like:

```
try {
  // some code that may or may not work
} catch (err) {
  // print out error or come up with a workaround
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Not having seen this error, how does it occur?

Comment: I'm loading three different datasets to my chart, each of them have a slightly different min and max, that's probably why this error keeps coming out. The full error message is `Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute width="-2"`

Comment: How do you swap between data sets?

Comment: Loading from server using $.getJSON or $.ajax

Comment: Do you have some live demo? It looks like a bug.

Comment: looking forward this too. So far Highcharts/Highstock will only use console to tell error